# Напишите функцию t8, которая при клике по .b-8 увеличивает z8 на единицу и запускает функцию showNumber

Tags: javascript, html, css

Дана переменная z8 равная 0. Напишите функцию t8, которая при клике по .b-8 увеличивает z8 на единицу и запускает функцию showNumber. Если число z8 равно 9, то при последующем клике становится равным 0.

Вот код

```
    const out8 = document.querySelector(".out-8");
const digit = [
  "нуль",
  "один",
  "два",
  "три",
  "четыре",
  "пять",
  "шесть",
  "семь",
  "восемь",
  "девять",
];
let z8 = 0;

function showNumber() {
  out8.innerHTML = digit[z8];
}

function t8() {
  z8++;
  showNumber();
}

document.querySelector(".b-8").addEventListener("click", t8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function t8() {
  if (z8 === 9) {
    z8 = 0;
  } else {
    z8++;
  }
  
  showNumber();
}
```

Почитайте про [условные ветвления](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Если число z8 равно 9, то при последующем клике становится равным 0.

Используйте тернарный или условный оператор

```js
var z8 = 0;

const digit = [
  "нуль",
  "один",
  "два",
  "три",
  "четыре",
  "пять",
  "шесть",
  "семь",
  "восемь",
  "девять",
];

function showNumber() {
  console.log(digit[z8]);
}

function t8() {
  z8 = (z8 == 9) ? 0 : (z8 + 1);
  showNumber();
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.b-8')).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', clickEvent => {
    t8();
  });
});
```